# Unexpected identifier using font-awesome dynamically

Tags: font-awesome

When I try to input a new line in a table containing a font-awesome element the browser throws a syntax error: Unexpected Identifier.

If I use the same syntax in a static element there is no problem. However, when I use it in the following js method I get the mentioned error:

```
function addCheckpoint(table) {

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var cDate = row.insertCell(0);
    var cType = row.insertCell(1);
    var cLocation = row.insertCell(2);
    var cDriver = row.insertCell(3);
    var cDriverFee = row.insertCell(4);
    var cFuel = row.insertCell(5);
    var cDelete = row.insertCell(6);
    var myClass = "form-control";

    var date = document.createElement("input");
    date.type = "date";
    date.class = myClass;
    cDate.appendChild(date);

    ...

    cDelete.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-times fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it creating a js file with all the scripts and import it at the bottom.